# what's the benefit of using the following when dealing with iterators

Tags: c++, visual-c++

For iterator, I saw some code use

```
(*iterator).first
```

but I think I can use the following

```
iterator->first
```

what's the advantage use one over another? which is better?

Comment: They're are equivalent. But consider  an iterator over a vector of vectors. It makes a slight difference in syntax if you want to access the element's `operator[]`, for example. `(*it)[0]` vs `it->operator[](0)`. The former looks a bit weird.

Comment: @jrok I'd argue that neither syntax is exactly "weird free" :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It could be worse `it.operator*().operator[](0)` :)

Comment: And I meant to say "the latter", not "former".

Comment: considering the array operator, the former is better, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

There is no advantage in using either of these statements, they will both compile to exactly the same machine code.

I would however say that the second one is slightly clearer, but this is simply personal preference.

Comment: I'd say more than slightly clearer.  Unless, as jrok points out in a comment, overloaded operators are involved.

Comment: I wouldn't pass the first form on a review.

Answer (score 1):

Readability.

The second one (to me IMHO) is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of the second one (as syntax) may be underlined whenever u have several pointers pointing to each other and the last one is pointing to the object you need. 
The code `p1->p2->obj` is clearer then `(*(*p1).p2).obj`. Imagine doing reference when you have 3 or more pointers. It is also the perfect place to have syntax errors.
If someone reads your code (even you) it will be clear what you were doing whenever you write your code using `->`operator.